# How Hide/remove div after delete ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am fetching image with "id"(dynamic) and  i want to delete image using ajax, Image is deleted successfully but unable to hide (div) dynamically (which i deleted)

Here is my html code

```
<?php 
$banner=$store->banner;
if(!empty($banner))
        {   
            $ban = explode(',', $banner);
            $i="1";
foreach($ban as $key => $img)
            {
                $img;
                $info=$img;
?>  
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $store->id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="imgname" name="imgname" value="<?php echo $img; ?>">
            
            <div class="form-group" id="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <!-- Creating div with id (dynamic) -->
            <label for="status">image <?php  ?></label>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/<?php echo $img; ?>" width="80" height="80">
            <a class="btn-sm btn-danger text-light" onclick="deleteFun(<?php echo $key; ?>)" href="#"> Delete</a>
            </div>
<?php 
            $i++;
            }
        }
?>
```

Here is my ajax function,I just want to hide div(which i select/deleted),How can i do this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteFun(ImgId)
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this banner ?")) {
            var imgname = $('#imgname').val();
            var id = $('#id').val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('upload_controller/deleteImage'); ?>", 
            data: {'id': id,'imgname':imgname,'ImgId':ImgId},
            success: function(data){ 
            $("#ImgId").remove();
            
              console.log(data);
                } 
             });
                }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#ImgId")` looks like a typo - you've hardcoded "ImgId" as a string instead of it being a variable. Try `$("#"+ImgId)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS, you have to specify DIV id as a concatenated value to target the specific id as the id you are taking is coming in to the function as an argument.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteFun(ImgId)
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this banner ?")) {
            var imgname = $('#imgname').val();
            var id = $('#id').val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('upload_controller/deleteImage'); ?>", 
            data: {'id': id,'imgname':imgname,'ImgId':ImgId},
            success: function(data){ 
            $("#" +ImgId).hide();
            
              console.log(data);
                } 
             });
                }
        }
</script>
```